# Sending POST request with payload using a module requests

Tags: python, post, python-requests

How to send a POST request with this payload (optional: with file)? Should I send all of headers for proper work of it?

This doesn't work:

```
data = {"to":"6642","send":"1","go":"1","id":"6642"}
f = open("f.jpg","rb")
r = requests.post(url,data=data,files={"f.jpg":f})
```

parameters and payload

[image: parameters and payload]

Sorry for my English and thanks for answers!

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a problem description (and please include screenshots in your question, not as a link)

Comment: @thebjorn: The OP doesn't have a rep high enough to include images in their question.

Comment: @martineau sorry, didn't realize you needed rep to include images..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this, I hope you attached the whole payload.

```
data = {'to':'6642',
        'send'='1',
        'go':'1',
        'id':'6642',
        "walltext":"TEST",
        "wallsend":"TEST"}
files  = {'file2':open("f.jpg","rb")
r = requests.post(url,data=data,files = files)
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. I already decided the problem. But 'to', 'send' and other need to be written in 'params=', cuz they are in URL, like params in GET request (I have not specified this).
Done it like this:
```params = {
    "to":"8994",
    "send":"1",
    "go":"1",
    "id":"8994"
    }

data = {
    "walltext":"123"
    }

upload_result = requests.post(url, params=params, files=file, data=data)```
Anyway, thanks!